# Python Loops (for or while)

Tags: python, loops

I have to create a function that consumes 2 lists and a prime number and produces True if L is related over the prime number to M and False otherwise

Here is my code I thought it looked good but the problem is it does not produce False when it should, I cannot seem to find the error. Thank you to whomever can quickly find the problem!

Helper to tell me whether I have a prime or not

```
def is_prime(a):
    prime = True 
    if a < 2:
        prime = False
    else:
        for i in (2, a):
            if a%i == 0:
                prime = False
                break
    return prime
```

Main function where the problem seems to occur

```
def check_related_over_prime(L,M,p):
    related_over_prime = True
    for i in range(len(L)):
        if is_prime(i):   
            difference =  L[i] - M[i]
            if (difference % p != 0):
                related_over_prime = False
                break
    return related_over_prime
```

for example: Here is a test that passes when it should and a test that passes when it should fail

Test1: `p = 3 -> True`

```
L1 = [0,1,4, 5, 6,10]
M1 = [0,1,1,-1,10, 1]
check.expect('T1', check_related_over_prime(L1,M1,3), True)
```

Test2: `p = 3 -> False`

```
L2 = [0,1,4, 5, 6,10]
M2 = [0,1,0,1,10, 11]
check.expect('T2', check_related_over_prime(L2,M2,3), False)
```

Answer (score 2):

`for i in (2, a):` should be `for i in range(2, a)`. `(2, a)` is a tuple and your for checks only values 2 and `a`, not all that are in between.

Comment: Thank you! It was bothering me like crazy much appreciated!

Comment: You're welcome ;) As a general suggestion, when you have problems finding errors in loops just stick around some `print("I entered the loop with number {}".format(i))`, `print("I am in the if statement")`, etc. so that you'll see what's going on. Also, please mark the answer as such so that the question can be considered solved :)